# Nodejs odbc - Insert statement doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to insert data into an Access file (.accdb) using nodejs 'odbc' library..

My select querys are working, however when i try to insert i get nothing inserted in my db.

```
const odbc = require('odbc')

const connectionString = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Desktop\\REPOS\\Project\\TestDB.accdb'

const connection = odbc.connect(connectionString, (error, connection) => {
    // const query = "SELECT * FROM Tasks"
    const query = "INSERT INTO Tasks (Cl, BLX) VALUES (\'SWI\', \'GIV\') "
    connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) { 
            console.error(error) 
        }

        console.log(result)
    })
})
```

The INSERT query works if i run it directly on Access, which denies the possibility of a typo.

The weird thing is, the SELECT statement works through nodejs.. Which means that connection is not problem as well

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Try removing the backslash characters. Never seen this. The SQL engine needs to see these apostrophes as special characters, not literal text.

Comment: I've also tried without the backlash and also with template string format.. Didn't work.
Still 100% sure the name of the columns/data type is correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering to my own question, it may help someone in the same position..)

The connection needs to be closed in order to properly execute the query!

Example:

```
const odbc = require('odbc')

const connectionString = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Desktop\\REPOS\\Project\\TestDB.accdb'

const connection = odbc.connect(connectionString, (error, connection) => {
    // const query = "SELECT * FROM Tasks"
    const query = "INSERT INTO Tasks (Cl, BLX) VALUES (\'SWI\', \'GIV\') "
    connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) { 
            console.error(error) 
        }

        console.log(result)

        connection.close()
    })
})
```